# Адаптивные изображения круговом меню

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

Можно ли разместить в сектора кругового меню адаптивные изображения?

Пример кода кругового меню: http://codepen.io/Fess/pen/adOgRN?editors=110

```
.circle-menu li {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(0deg) skew(30deg);
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(60deg) skew(30deg);
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(120deg) skew(30deg);
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotate(180deg) skew(30deg);
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(5) {
    transform: rotate(240deg) skew(30deg);
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(6) {
    transform: rotate(300deg) skew(30deg);
}
.circle-menu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    margin-top: 54%;
    margin-left: 54%;
    background: black no-repeat 50% 40%;
    transform: skew(-30deg) rotate(-60deg);
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.circle-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(1) a {
    background: pink;
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(1):hover a {
    background: red;
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(2) a {
    background: blue;
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(3) a {
    background: blue;
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(4) a {
    background: blue;
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(5) a {
    background: blue;
}
.circle-menu li:nth-child(6) a {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: а в чём проблема? `background: url(...` + `background-size: cover;`

Comment: мне кажется, вопрос неоднозначный... что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Большое спасибо, да что то затупил я. У меня не работало потому что я обращался не к ссылкам, а к элементам списка и так как там трансформированный div то и изображение тоже искажалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял из комментариев, автору подошёл мой вариант с `background` и `background-size: cover;`. В данном случаи можно пустить фоном картинку, и выставить `background-size` в значение `cover`, что позволит изображению быть масштабируемым.

```
...
.circle-menu li:nth-child(1) a {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
    background-size: cover;
}
...
```